# Super User twitter account tweeting meta questions

Tags: support, twitter

Finally, we have a [Super User twitter account](https://twitter.com/#!/StackSuper_User) albeit with a el-crappy name ( thanks, [twitter](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118?m=1594027#1594027)!), Still hurrah!

But.... one of the questions that was tweeted, turned out to be a [meta question](https://twitter.com/#!/StackSuper_User/status/102535697080123392):

[image: meta question]

I'm not so sure if meta questions should be tweeted. IMO the Super User feed should restrict itself to activity from the main site, not the meta.

Comment: -1 *Now that we finally have another way to get people to the meta... :(*

Comment: @Tom Wijsman:  I agree with your comment, except for the downvote -- the way I see it, both the question and your comment make excellent points.

Comment: @Randolf: Votes on meta are used for (dis)agreement, not for clarity/usefulness.

Comment: @Tom Wijsman:  Ah, I see, and it's in the FAQ (although the points still count on the main site, don't they?):  http://meta.superuser.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @Randolf: For that reason, there is no such thing as reputation on meta. The only meta where you can gather and lose reputation is [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design.

The twitter bot will do a few new things now:

[Would allowing moderators to update their Stack Exchange sites' Twitter accounts improve visibility and offer more value?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-accounts/101340#101340)

Comment: I actually find it very useful to get notified of Meta discussions on sites I frequent